# WP Dashboard -> Posts-> Filter > BUG!

Tags: filters, dashboard, bug

I've a problem in the Posts List in the Dashboard.

When I filter (by POST) the Posts the results aren't the same than to pass the category slug by GET.

Here the examples:

by GET:
[image: by GET]

by POST:
[image: by POST]

Can you help me?  Where is the error?

- In the DB (MySql)?
- In the core code?
- In the sever setting?
- In the WP config setting?

I'm going crazy!

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: At a guess, I'd say that category_name is not a supported parameter for that URL.

Comment: The problem is when i try to filter the posts for category in posts list.
As you can see in the screenshots the filter doesn't work.
But when i come to the posts list from the category list page the posts are filtered (by the "category_name" parameter).

Comment: are you using the `pre_get_posts` filter anywhere? Note that this filter is not just for the frontend, it runs in WP Admin too, also how are you filtering in a way that uses `category_name`? Note that if you had used `POST` there wouldn't be URL parameters as that's `GET`, yet clearly there are URL parameters so both of them must be a `GET` request not a `POST` request